# find most frequently used products / items by a specific user

Tags: c#, aforge, accord.net

I am developing a web API for an enterprise application. In current scenario, when any user clicks on any drop down control, a request is made to the server, now the ADO.Net code simply fetches the list from the appropriate table in **alphabetical order** and response is returned as JSON. This is pretty straightforward.

Now, what I want to do is, to return most frequently used items by a specific user in my response. For Example, I have a drop down for all items by a company. Now user A mostly use item 1, item 2, item 3, while user B mostly use item 4, item 5, item 6. Now rather than returning a constant list in alphabetical order each time, I want to return a list to user A in which item 1, item 2, item 3 should be on top while for user B item 4, item 5, item 6 should be on top.

I have searched it and learnt that I can do this type of stuff by machine learning algorithms. I am totally unaware from this domain. I found AFORGE.NET and Accord.NET as some good frameworks for .NET, but I am still unclear about how can I do it?

Please somebody guide me, how can I achieve it?

Best Regards

Comment: Seems you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Why can't you keep a count for the number of "uses" for each item and increase that every time an item is used, and then order your list by that count before returning it?

Comment: i dont simply want to keep a total count. I want to return the list on user basis. most frequently used items by any user. User A use "PEPSI" frequently but user B does not need that. So for user B "PEPSI" should be down the list. while for user A it should be on top

Comment: You can simply keep the count per user.

Comment: Suppose I have 50+ drop downs each having 500-2000 items. and total users are 150+. I want to handle this stuff in C# processes.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, you must keep account of each item used per user. Machine learning is not magic, you must feed it with actual data. That is what Big Data is about. In your case, is a more simple task. As @SaebAmini has told you, just keep the count for user/item and order by that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Saeb is correct. You can modify your DB to have a many-to-many relationship between Users and Products. The Users_And_Products table should store a count for any item that has been viewed:

```
UserID ProductID Count
001    123       1      
001    010       4
002    123       5
002    050       4
002    051       3
```

As you can see, you will not need to store a count for Products that have been viewed zero times, but just keep track of the ones that have been viewed at all. This then becomes a trivial SQL query (`where UserID='001' orderby Count desc`).